# pythonのtkinterのインポートができません。

Tags: python, windows-10

pythonを学び始めた初心者です。自分なりに調べたのですが解決できなかったので皆様のお力をお貸しいただけたら、と思い質問させていただきます。

**環境：**
Windows 10 64bit
Python 3.6.2 [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

**問題：**
インタラクティブシェルからtkinterをインポートしようとしたところ、次のようなエラーメッセージが表示され、インポートができませんでした。

以下`>>> import tkinter`の実行結果

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 は有効な Win32 アプリケーションではありません。
```

更に、コマンドプロンプトから「python -m tkinter」と入力してみたところ、

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 は有効な Win32 アプリケーションではありません。
```

との結果でした。いったい何が原因で、どのように対処したら、tkinterをインポートできるのでしょうか。おそらく、大変初歩的な質問かと思われ、恐縮なのですが、ご教示いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Tkがインストールされていないのでは?

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。python3.6.3をインストールしたところ、tkinterのインポートができるようになりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これらが関連する質問だと思いますが、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/importerror-dll-load-failed-importing-tkinter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289758/error-importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-with

Windows 10 **64bit**にPythonの**32bit**バージョンをインストールしているのが原因と思われます。

いったんPython(32bit)をアンインストールして、64bit版をインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Python64bit版のインストーラーは↓の`Windows x86-64 executable installer`と`Windows x86-64 web-based installer`です。
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/

Comment: ご教示いただきました通り、既存のpythonをアンインストールしたのち、python3.6.3　インストールしたところ、tkinterのインポートができるようになりました。ありがとうございました！